# Array of NSLocalizedStrings in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, nslocalizedstring

I am attempting to convert some code to Swift but am stumbling with some code to add `NSLocalizedString`s to an array property. I defined the array as an array of `String`s. I'm attempting to add the objects using `+=` just as the documentation states, but I am receiving error `Could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied arguments`.

I'm sure it's a simple mistake, but I've tried a few different combinations (appending `as String[]` to the end, or after the var name, or appending `= []` to the declaration, etc) and cannot get it to work. Would appreciate some explanation of what's going on.

```
//Property:
var localizedTitles: String[]

//In init:
localizedTitles += [NSLocalizedString("My String", tableName: nil, bundle: nil, value: "My String", comment: "")]
```

Comment: `NSLocalizedString()` is a function, not a type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three problems / comments:

1. For some reason the bundle parameter to NSLocalizedString is not optional. You have to provide it an actual bundle.
2. You must initialize the array before trying to append to it.
3. You can define the array as an array of Strings since that is what NSLocalizedString returns.

Try this (I added some newlines to make it more readable in this format):

```
var localizedTitles : [String] = []
localizedTitles += NSLocalizedString(
    "My String",
    tableName: nil,
    bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(),
    value: "My String",
    comment: ""
    )
```

But because some of the parameters have default values, you can simply do:

```
var localizedTitles : [String] = []
localizedTitles += NSLocalizedString("My String", value: "My String", comment: "")
```

Comment: That did the trick. Interesting, the docs say a default value is given for `bundle` if not provided.

Comment: @Joey Ya, I think that is referring to the fact that the parameters have default parameters so you can just leave them out of the call. I updated my answer above with an example of just leaving them out.